# "Invalid backend model specified: auit_editor/customer_attribute_backend_groups" after deleting AuIt_Editor module

Tags: module, database, model, delete

I've just removed the AuIt_Editor module and now when I try to log in (or create a new account), I get the following error: `Invalid backend model specified: auit_editor/customer_attribute_backend_groups`

Note that I have flushed the cache, in backend, as wel as through n98-magerun and I've also deleted the var/cache folder (and as an extra precaution even the media/js and media/css (js and css merge is enabled) folders)

This is the output from my system.log

```
2017-01-12T15:52:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Auit/Editor/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Groups.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/src/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2017-01-12T15:52:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Auit/Editor/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Groups.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/src/app/code/local:/var/www/src/app/code/community:/var/www/src/app/code/core:/var/www/src/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/var/www/src/app/code/community/Zookal/Mock/Model/Mocks')  in /var/www/src/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2017-01-12T15:52:58+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Auit/Editor/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Groups.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/src/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2017-01-12T15:52:58+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Auit/Editor/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Groups.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/src/app/code/local:/var/www/src/app/code/community:/var/www/src/app/code/core:/var/www/src/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/var/www/src/app/code/community/Zookal/Mock/Model/Mocks')  in /var/www/src/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2017-01-12T15:53:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2017-01-12T15:53:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): default  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2017-01-12T15:53:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2017-01-12T15:53:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CacheController.php on line 82
2017-01-12T15:54:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2017-01-12T15:54:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): default  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2017-01-12T15:54:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2017-01-12T16:17:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2017-01-12T16:17:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): default  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2017-01-12T16:17:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^  in /var/www/src/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2017-01-12T16:23:35+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/aw_rma/sales/order/info.phtml
2017-01-12T16:31:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Auit/Editor/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Groups.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/src/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2017-01-12T16:31:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Auit/Editor/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Groups.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/src/app/code/local:/var/www/src/app/code/community:/var/www/src/app/code/core:/var/www/src/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/var/www/src/app/code/community/Zookal/Mock/Model/Mocks')  in /var/www/src/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

When I check the *eav_attribute* table in my database, there is a row there with following data:

```
attribute_id: 140
entity_type_id: 1
attribute_code: auit_group_ids
attribute_model: NULL
backend_model: auit_editor/customer_attribute_backend_groups
backend_type: text
backend_table: NULL
frontend_model: NULL
frontend_input: multiselect
frontend_label: SNM Groups
frontend_class: NULL
source_model: auit_editor/customer_attribute_source_groups
is_required: 0
is_user_defined: 0
default_value: NULL
is_unique: 0
note: NULL
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Is it safe to just delete that row? This is weird because I've searched the code and couldn't find any reference/stray class/... connected to this module and so it should not be an issue. So what's happening here?

Any help would be nuch appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important that, you need to remove database changes that is made by the removed module. Database changes which would be possible to occur by a module are :

- Any new tables which use to store specific data for the module.
- Any existing table changes (eg: adding or removing of a column).
- System configurations specific to the module.
- Eav attributes removal if any.
- and so on.

To get an idea on what are the changes which has done to the database by a module, you need to look inside `sql` directory files within a module.

> An ideal module is the one which also provides provision to remove all
>   kind of changes which has done to the application.

So in this case, do not hesitate to remove that attribute from your application.

Answer (score 0):

Nico,

Yes, you can safely delete that row now. This is one of those long-standing Magento issues: modules do not provide uninstall or cleanup routines so you sometimes need to modify the database directly.